# Accessing User ID as a variable in Google Tag Manager for mobile

Tags: firebase, mobile, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, userid

I'm getting started with Google Tag Manager for Android/iOS, and can't find a way to access the *User ID* as a variable. I can access *Firebase User Properties* and *Event Parameters* just fine.

So far, I've tried setting it using `FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId` and trying to access it as a User Property called `user_id` / `userId`.

Some workarounds I've thought of:

- Using a CustomVariableProvider (preferred)
- Setting the User ID as an Event Parameter (this wouldn't work with built-in events)

I'm just trying to make sure there's no built-in way of doing this before I resort to workarounds. Thanks!

[I was not able to find the User ID (or UID) in the list of built-in variables, see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo8oa.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in way, but it requires quite a sophisticated setup.

In GA version 4 the path is changed comparing to the previous version, where the same could be done much easier via "Tracking Info".

Here are the starting steps in GA4:

1. Open https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web
2. Bottom-left corner -> Admin -> Setup Assistant -> Advanced setup -> User ID
3. Follow the [instruction](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10110290?hl=en_GB&utm_id=ad#user-id&zippy=%2Cset-up-user-ids)

After that UserID will be available in GTM.

Video guide for exact steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVJMFVOXFUQ